Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my assembly code after adding everything I subtracted from stack?
basically my code is trying to read from an input.txt file and creates a new RECORD based on that data. I had someone look over my initial draft and they said that I did not allocate enough space in the stack, so I subtracted 208 from the stack and then made sure to add it back in the end, but I am still getting the same error. Is there something I am missing? By the way, I am running this on Windows using Cygwin.
this is my code

read_record:

pushq   %rbp         
    movq    %rsp, %rbp 


#lasname value can be r12 firstname r13 id r14


subq  $208, %rsp
pushq   %r12        
pushq   %r13
pushq   %r14



lea -100(%rbp), %r12
lea -200(%rbp),%r13
lea -208(%rbp),%r14



#scanf
     lea     scanstring(%rip),%rcx   #the string into %rcx
     movq %r12,%rdx    #lastname, second param    
     movq    %r13,%r8   # firstname to third param
     movq   (%r14),%r9  # id to r9 4 param
                            
    subq    $32,%rsp    
    call    scanf       
    addq    $32,%rsp


IFLOOP:
    cmp %eax, -1 
    je DONE
DONE:
    ret 

movq $34, %rdi

#p = malloc(sizeof(RECORD));
movq %rdi, %rcx
subq    $32,%rsp
    call malloc
addq    $32,%rsp

movq %rax, %r15

#r15 is p
#strlen(lastname)+1

#lastname plus 1
inc %r12

movq %r12, %rcx
subq    $32,%rsp
    call strlen
addq    $32,%rsp


#malloc(strlen(lastname)+1);
movq %rax, %rcx
subq    $32,%rsp
    call malloc
addq    $32,%rsp

#p->last_name = malloc(strlen(lastname)+1);
movq %rax, 0(%r15)

#reset r12
dec %r12


#strcpy(p->last_name,lastname)
movq 0(%r15), %rcx
movq %r12, %rdx

subq    $32,%rsp
    call strcpy
addq    $32,%rsp

#p->first_name = malloc(strlen(lastname)+1);
#strlen(lastname)+1

#lastname plus 1

inc %r12

movq %r12, %rcx
subq    $32,%rsp
    call strlen
addq    $32,%rsp
#reset r12
dec %r12

#malloc(strlen(lastname)+1);
movq %rax, %rcx
subq    $32,%rsp
    call malloc
addq    $32,%rsp

#p->first_name =
movq %rax, 8(%r15)


#strcpy(p->last_name,lastname)
movq 8(%r15), %rcx
movq %r13, %rdx

subq    $32,%rsp
    call strcpy
addq    $32,%rsp

movq 16(%r15), %r14

 movl %r15d,%eax

addq  $208, %rsp
popq    %r12        
popq    %r13
popq    %r14

    popq    %rbp
    retq 

#==========================================



############


.text
scanstring:
        .asciz  "%s %s %ld"


    .data
                .globl heap_count
    heap_count: .int   0      




Thanks everyone

je DONE; DONE: ret  makes no sense, the code will fall through to DONE anyway. Also that ret will not restore the stack.

Also your pops are in the wrong order.

Not only are the pops in the wrong order, the addq to add back the stack offset should be after the pops.
